# Danger of using non-sanitized user input in PHP switch statement

Tags: php

Is there any concern to use a non-sanitized user input in a switch statement?  Thanks

```
switch($_GET['userInput']) {}
```

Comment: No I don't see why there would be any.

Comment: Wouldn't it depend to some degree what you do with the input within that switch statement?

Comment: Yes but that's not the question at all. I'm pretty sure he is sanitizing it when he needs it but he was scared that a value could "break" his switch

Comment: @WillemEllis.  Just using the switch part to get to the associated label.

Comment: Okay! Just thought I would mention it for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other then your switch statement possibly not working properly, no, there aren't any security issues with this.

Comment: Thanks John,  Didn't think so, but wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0):

You should never accept a variable in the wild, without first sanitizing it in some way, shape, or form regardless of what it is being used for.

Comment: Why not if there is not danger?

Comment: That's not true. Actually, switch may be used as a form of sanitization.

Comment: Because if your switch breaks from a malformed GET then a user has access to your error report. I said in the wild. if you are doing it for your own use, there is no reason to sanitize it.

Comment: There is also a default for switch which will catch these.

Comment: How would a switch break from a malformed `$_GET`? It's just a string. `switch("aæøå8²½ß´1123!æ!\"#%/(") {` is still just a string, no matter how many "weird" characters are in it.

Comment: @HydraIO : in which case would his switch break from a malformed GET ?

Comment: @zerkms there is no doubt that it can be. I just don't like the idea of showing a real user an error report.

Comment: I stand corrected, you are correct, it would not throw an error under regular circumstance. I have mine piped to error. I retract my previous statement.

Answer (score 0):

There's no danger in the select statement itself, **however** there might very well be in your cases depending on what you put in there (file creations/writing/manipulation and database handling can both be very dangerous if you don't sanitize/control your input).

Comment: Understood.  I have protection for those issues.